# PySimpleGUI - Binding shortcut key to one element of a sub-layout

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Thank you for reading this.

I am searching for a standard solution but couldn't find one.
I have a simple layout made out of two layouts and the first layout is the one used to create the window.

[image: MainGUI]

I want to bind shorcut keys to only the right buttons.
They are not receiving the events at all, only always the first InputText element.
I need to have the InputText elements also receiving events and I could achieved that already.
I need that kind of layouts' architecture for a more complex GUI (Tab element and so on).

I have prepared one script that can contain my problem.

```
import PySimpleGUI as Sg

input_folder_layout = [Sg.Text("input folder",
                               size=(20, 1),
                               background_color="#64778D"),
                       Sg.InputText(default_text="",
                                    key="input_folder",
                                    size=(65, 1),
                                    enable_events=True),
                       Sg.FolderBrowse("...",
                                       size=(6, 1),
                                       key="input_folder_browse",
                                       enable_events=True)]
output_folder_layout = [Sg.Text("output folder", size=(20, 1),
                                background_color="#64778D"),
                        Sg.InputText(default_text="",
                                     key="output_folder",
                                     size=(65, 1),
                                     enable_events=True),
                        Sg.FolderBrowse("...", 
                                        size=(6, 1),
                                        key="output_folder_browse",
                                        enable_events=True)]

ui_layout = [input_folder_layout, output_folder_layout]

Sg.ChangeLookAndFeel("DarkBlue2")
window = Sg.Window("UI Test", ui_layout, finalize=True)

window.bind("<Ctrl_R><i>", "CTRL-i")
window.bind("<Ctrl_R><o>", "CTRL-o")

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event != "__TIMEOUT__" and event is not None:
        if event in ("input_folder_browse", "CTRL-i"):
            print("input folder browse event found")
        
        if event in ("output_folder_browse", "CTRL-o"):
            print("output folder browse event found")

    if event == Sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    window.refresh()

window.close()
window = None
```

I am using PySimpleGUI==4.60.3 and Python==3.9.13.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding for `ctrl` key is `Control`, not `ctrl`.

```py
window.bind("<Control_R><i>", "CTRL-i")
window.bind("<Control_R><o>", "CTRL-o")
```